# Elasticsearch always uses the default mapping

Tags: csv, elasticsearch

Am trying to create an index using "[CSV River Plugin for ElasticSearch](https://github.com/AgileWorksOrg/elasticsearch-river-csv)", my csv file contains String, long and date values.

My problem is : 
 - ElasticSearch always consider long values as string ( with default mapping ) and when i try to create a specific mapping to be used, it changes long type to string type.
 - So, is there a way to tell ElasticSearch ***Don't map everything as string ?***

Any suggestion please?

Thank you

Comment: I think issue is due to csv, where all values are considerd as string. So, you should provide explicit mapping, or just use other file formats.